# jconsole can not connect ssl1?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, jconsole

This is my very first time to use jconsole.

The final goal of using this is measuring using memory redis uses. However, since this is my first time I want to just begin with small java project which just prints a phrase.

Here is my source code.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int cnt = 0;
        while(true){
            if(cnt == 100)
                break;

            System.out.println("Save me from the nap!");
            Thread.sleep(1000*30);
            cnt++;
        }
    }
};
```

After I wrote this code, I tried to run jconsole. So I ran this program in eclipse, at the same time, I execute 'jconsole' command in terminal. like below.

```
>jconsole
```

A UI interface poped up and I can see process ID of my program:

[image]

So I choose 'local' and my process ID and press connect button.

But it shows an error message like this.

```
ConnectionFailedSSL1
ConnectionFailedSSL2
<Cancel> <Insecure>
```

Do I had to extra job to execute jconsole? Give me some specific instruction to use this. I really do not have any concept of 'SSL'.(All I know about this is SSL is abbreviation of Secure Socket Layer)

My OS is OSX Mavericks.

Comment: What happens if you select "insecure" rather than "cancel"?

Comment: @WarrenDew When I press insecure button, it works. Thanks. However, when I post this question here, it did not work. Hard to reenact that situation. Thanks again :D (Should I erase this post?)

Comment: Don't erase the post.  Someone else may have the same problem; leaving the post here allows them to find the answer through a search, without having to post a new question.

Comment: If it matters, I could not duplicate with OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently jconsole cannot authenticate the certificate it received on making a direct SSL connection to the JVM.  Since it's on the local machine, it should be safe to select "insecure" and connect without certificate authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned something new today. have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure that the JVM and jconsole are the same version - particularly 64 vs 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

we've seen the above behavior complaining with "ConnectionFailedSSL1" even for a local connection with auth/ssl turned off (all defaults) with 1.7.0_45-b18 and it goes away with 1.7.0_75-b13, back to how it used to be with java 1.6.